# Difference between String#equals and String#contentEquals methods

Tags: java, string, equality

What is the difference between the [`String#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method and the [`String#contentEquals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contentEquals%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method?

Answer (score 206):

The [`String#equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) not only compares the String's contents, but also checks if the other object is also an instance of a `String`. The [`String#contentEquals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence)) only compares the contents (the character sequence) and does **not** check if the other object is also an instance of `String`. It can be anything as long as it is an implementation of [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) which covers a.o. [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html), [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html), [`CharBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/CharBuffer.html), etc.

Comment: So, is it like the operators `==` (contentEquals) and `===` (equals) in javascript?

Comment: @anestv In Java, the `==` operator will only permit you comparing the **references** not the *content* of two objects.

Comment: @Alex to clarify, the == operator in Java is for checking whether two objects point to the same location in memory, or whether two primitive types (byte, short, int, long, float, double, char, boolean) are equal.

Comment: @Stephan, the `==` mentioned is only JavaScript; it's never mentioned regarding Java.

Comment: @anestv, there are differences (`==` in JavaScript is far looser than `contentEquals`, which won't touch numbers, for example), but you're correct about `equals` checking for an exact type match **with `Strings`** (other classes might be looser with types in their `equals` methods).

Answer (score 62):

To put it easily: *`String.contentEquals()` is the smarter brother of `String.equals()`, because it can be more free in the implementation than `String.equals()`.*

There are some reasons why there is a separate `String.contentEquals()` method. The most important reason I think is:

- The `equals` method has to be reflexive. That means that: `x.equals(y) == y.equals(x)`. This implies that `aString.equals(aStringBuffer)` would have to be the same as `aStringBuffer.equals(aString)`. This would require the Java API developers to make some special implementation for Strings in the `equals()` method of StringBuffer, StringBuilder and CharSequence as well. This would be a mess.

This is where `String.contentEquals` comes in. This is a **standalone method** that does **not** have to **follow the strict requirements and rules** for `Object.equals`. This way, you can implement the sense of *"equal content"* more freely. This allows you to make intelligent comparisons between a StringBuffer and a String, for example.

And to say what exactly the difference is:

- `String.contentEquals()` can compare the contents of a `String`, a `StringBuilder`, a `StringBuffer`, a `CharSequence` and all derived classes of these. If the parameter is of type String, then `String.equals()` get executed.
- `String.equals()` only compares String objects. All other object types are considered as not equal.
- `String.contentEquals()` can compare `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` in an intelligent way. It does **not** call the heavy `toString()` method, which copies the whole content to a new String object. Instead, it compares with the underlying `char[]` array, which is great.

Answer (score 34):

This answer was already posted by **dbw** but he deleted it but he had some very valid points for the difference while comparing execution time, what exceptions are thrown,

If you look at the source code [String#equals](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [String#contentEquals](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) it is clear that there are two overridden methods for `String#contentEquals` one which take `StringBuilder` and other `CharSequence`.
The difference between them,

1. `String#contentEquals` will throw NPE if the argument supplied is `null` but `String#equals` will return `false`
2. `String#equals` compares the content only when the argument supplied is `instance of String` otherwise it will return `false` in all other cases but on the other hand `String#contentEquals` checks the content of all the objects which implement interface [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html).
3. You can also tweak the code so that `String#contentEquals` return the wrong result or result you want by overriding `equals` method of the argument passed as shown below but you can not do those tweaks with `String#equals`.
   **Below code will always produce `true`** as long as `s` contains any `string` which is 3 character long

   ```
       String s= new String("abc");// "abc";
       System.out.println(s.contentEquals(new CharSequence() 
       {

           @Override
           public CharSequence subSequence(int arg0, int arg1) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               return null;
           }

           @Override
           public int length() {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               return 0;
           }

           @Override
           public char charAt(int arg0) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               return 0;
           }


           @Override
           public boolean equals(Object obj) 
           {
              return true;
           }
       }));
   ```
4. `String#contentEquals` will be slower then `String#Equals` in the case when argument supplied is `instance of String` and the length of both `String` is same but contents are not equal.
   **Example** if the string are `String s = "madam"` and `String argPassed = "madan"` then `s.contentEquals(argPassed)` will take almost double execution time in this case as compared to `s.equals(argPassed)`
5. If the content length are not same for both the strings then function `String#contentEquals` will have better performance then `String#Equals` in almost all possible cases.

**One more point to add to his answer**

6. `String#contentEquals` of a `String` object will also compare to the `StringBuilder` contents and provide the appropriate result while `String#Equals` will return `false`

Comment: @dbw this answer is from the answer you posted

Comment: @dbw Besides, why did you delete your post anyway?

Answer (score 15):

- `String` class `equals(Object o)` method does only `String` comparison. But `contentEquals(CharSequence cs)` checks for classes extends `AbstractStringBuilder` i.e.  `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder` and `String` class also (They all are of type `CharSequence`).

  ```
  String str = "stackoverflow";
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
  System.out.println(str.equals(builder));
  System.out.println(str.contentEquals(builder));
  ```

**output:**

```
false
true
```

The output of first stmt is `false` because `builder` is not of type `String` so `equals()` returns `false` but the `contentEquals()` checks for the content of all the type like `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer`, `String` and as the content is same hence `true`.

- `contentEquals` will throw `NullPointerException` if the argument supplied is `null` but `equals()` will return false because the equals() checks for instanceOf ( *`if (anObject instance of String)`* ) which returns false if the argument is `null`.

Answer (score 14):

**`contentEquals(CharSequence cs)`:**

- Lets you check equality of given string value with any implementation instance of interface `java.lang.CharacterSequence` (eg, `CharBuffer`, `Segment`, `String`, `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder` )

**`equals(Object anObject)`:**

- Lets you check equality of given string value with any instance of type `java.lang.String` **only**

**RTFC :)**

Since reading the source is the best way to understand it, I am sharing the implementations of both the methods (as of jdk 1.7.0_45)

```
public boolean contentEquals(CharSequence cs) {
    if (value.length != cs.length())
        return false;
    // Argument is a StringBuffer, StringBuilder
    if (cs instanceof AbstractStringBuilder) {
        char v1[] = value;
        char v2[] = ((AbstractStringBuilder) cs).getValue();
        int i = 0;
        int n = value.length;
        while (n-- != 0) {
            if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                return false;
            i++;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // Argument is a String
    if (cs.equals(this))
        return true;
    // Argument is a generic CharSequence
    char v1[] = value;
    int i = 0;
    int n = value.length;
    while (n-- != 0) {
        if (v1[i] != cs.charAt(i))
            return false;
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String) anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                        return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

---

There is another method of String#contentEquals():

```
public boolean contentEquals(StringBuffer sb) {
    synchronized(sb) {
        return contentEquals((CharSequence)sb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`equals()` and `contentEquals()` are two methods in `String` class to compare two `strings` and `string` with `StringBuffer`.

The parameters of `contentEquals()` are `StringBuffer` and `String(charSequence)`. `equals()` is used to compare two `strings` and `contentEquals()` is used to compare the contents of `String` and `StringBuffer`.

Method `contentEquals` and  `equals` are

```
public boolean contentEquals(java.lang.StringBuffer);
public boolean contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence);
public boolean equals(Object o)
```

Here is an code which describes both methods

```
public class compareString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "hello";    
        String str2 = "hello";

        StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("hello");
        StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer("world");

        boolean result1 = str1.equals(str2);        // works nice and returns true
        System.out.println(" str1.equals(str2) - "+ result1);

        boolean result2 = str1.equals(sb1);         // works nice and returns false
        System.out.println(" str1.equals(sb1) - "+ result2);

        boolean result3 = str1.contentEquals(sb1);  // works nice and returns true
        System.out.println(" str1.contentEquals(sb1) - "+ result3);

        boolean result4 = str1.contentEquals(sb2);  // works nice and returns false
        System.out.println(" str1.contentEquals(sb2) - "+ result4);

        boolean result5 = str1.contentEquals(str2);  // works nice and returns true
        System.out.println(" str1.contentEquals(str2) - "+ result5);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 str1.equals(str2) - true
 str1.equals(sb1) - false
 str1.contentEquals(sb1) - true
 str1.contentEquals(sb2) - false
 str1.contentEquals(str2) - true
```

Answer (score 7):

The `contentEquals()` method checks is the contents are same between a `String`, `StringBuffer`, etc which some kind of char sequence.

Answer (score 7):

**String#equals** takes Object as an argument and checks it is instance of String object or not. If the argument object is String Object then it compares content character by character. It returns true in case content of both string objects are same.

**String#contentEquals** takes CharSequence interface as an argument. CharSequence can be implements in 2 ways-by using i) String class  or (ii) AbstractStringBuilder( parent class of StringBuffer, StringBuilder)

In **contentEquals()**  length is compared before any object instance check. If length is same then it checks argument object is instance of AbstractStringBuilder or not. If it is so(i.e. StringBuffer or StringBuilder ) then content is checked character by character. In case argument is an instance of String object then String#equals called from String#contentEquals.

So in short,

**String#equals** compares the content character by character in case argument is String object also. And **String#contentEquals** compares the content in case argument object implement CharSequence interface.

String#contentEquals is slower in case we compare two same length string content as String#contentEquals internally calls String#equals for String object.

In case we try to compare objects with difference content length (say "abc" with "abcd") then String#contentEquals is faster than String#equals. Because length is compared before any object instance checking.

Answer (score 6):

BTW, the historical reason for the difference is that String originally had no superclass, so String.equals() takes a String as its argument. When CharSequence was introduced as the superclass of String, it needed an equality test of its own that worked across all CharSequence implementations, and that would not collide with the equals() already in use by String... so we got CharSequence.contentEquals(), which is inherited by String.

If CharSequence has been present in Java 1.0, we would probalby have only CharSequence.equals() and String would simply implement that.

Ah, the joys of evolving languages...

Comment: Java `equals` is "broken" because it accepts everything, but usually it is an error to compare a `String` to `List`: but `equals(Object)` doesn't help to identify the problem at compile time requiring costly runtime test coverage.