# equals or contentEquals when comparing strings

Tags: java, string, equals

I can see that `contentEquals` is useful for comparing char sequences but I can't find anywhere specifying which method is the best to use when comparing two strings.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476600/difference-between-stringequals-and-stringcontentequals-methods) mentions the differences between both methods but it doesn't explicitly say what to do with two strings.

I can see one advantage of usng `contentEquals` is that if the variable passed in has its type changed, a compilation error will be thrown. A disadvantage could be the speed of execution.

Should I always use `contentEquals` when comparing strings or only use it if there are different objects extending `CharSequence`?

Comment: With two strings, use `equals`.

Comment: If you use `contentEquals` to compare two strings, it will call `equals` anyway.

Comment: There is no point in using `contentEquals` when comparing 2 Strings, `equals` is all you need. String is always a String, can't be anything else (it's final).

Comment: When comparing 2 string you should use _equals_. BTW if both the `CharSequence` objects are instances of `String`, then contentEquals() invoke internally _equals_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should use `String#equals` when comparing the content fo two Strings. Only use `contentEquals` if one of the Object is not of the type String.

1) it is less confusing. Every Java developer should know what the method is doing, but `contentEquals` is a more specialised method and therefore less known.

2) It is faster, as you can see in the implementation of `contentEquals` it calls `equals` after checking if the sequence is of type `AbstractStringBuilder` so you save the execution time of that check. But even if the execution would be slower this should not be the first point to make your decision on. First go for readability.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of `contentEquals()` is support for objects that implement a  `CharSequence`. When you have a `StringBuilder` it would be wasteful to call `StringBuilder.toString()` just so you can use `equals()` a moment later. In this case `contentEquals()` helps to avoid allocating a new `String` to do the comparison.

When comparing two `String` objects just use `equals()`.